# GNU parallel and script not starting

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I'm working for an academic paper on some bioinformatics work (and I'll quote it as asked by the author ;) ) and I need to speed up my bash.

It's basically a `bash` script which runs a loop to iterate files and look for strings with `awk`.

I followed the manual and using `parallel -a ./script.sh`. I had issues with the variable so I changed it for `-q` and there it seems that the script does not start at all, although I have no error message.

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't get what. Previously, I had to pipe it with ::: because I had an input file, but this script does not have any.

The script :

```
#!/bin/bash
files_chrM_ID="concat_chrM_*"
bam_directory="../bam/"
for ID_file in ${files_chrM_ID}
do
    echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $ID_file is being treated"
    sample=${ID_file: -12}
    sample=${sample:0:8}
    echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $sample is being treated"
    for bam_file_target in "${bam_directory}"*"${sample}"*".bam"
    do
        echo $bam_file_target // $sample
        out_file=${ID_file:0:-4}_ON_${bam_file_target:8:-4}.sam
        echo "$out_file will be created"
        echo "samtools and awk starting"
        
        samtools view -@ 6 $bam_file_target | awk -v st="$ID_file" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t";ORS="\r\n"; while (getline < st) {st_array[$1]=$2}} {if ($1 in st_array) {print $0, st_array[$1], "target"}}' >> $out_file
        echo "$out_file done."
    done
done
```

and my command :

```
parallel -q ./script.sh
```

Comment: May be parallel calls some sort of execv() to run the command. So, as it is a bash script, you may need to add "#!/bin/bash" in the very first line of your script.

Comment: Thanks Rachid, it is already but my copy/paste did not work !

Comment: I did a try with "parallel -- command.sh" and it works

Comment: You can also do "parallel command.sh -- 1 2 3" : each instance of the script will be passed one of the parameters (1, 2 and 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Parallel is not magic: You cannot tell it to parallelize any script.

Instead you need to tell it what to parallelize and how.

In general you need to think that you have to generate a list of commands that you want run in parallel and then give this list to GNU Parallel.

In the script you have 2 `for` loops and a pipe. All three can be parallelized by using GNU Parallel. It is, however, not certain it will make sense: There is an overhead in parallelizing and if the current implementation utilized the CPU and disk resources optimally, then you will not see a speedup by parallelizing.

A `for` loop like this

```
for x in x-value1 x-value2 x-value3 ... x-valueN; do
  # do something to $x
done
```

is parallelized by:

```
myfunc() {
  x="$1"
  # do something to $x
}
export -f myfunc
parallel myfunc ::: x-value1 x-value2 x-value3 ... x-valueN
```

A pipe in the form of `A | B | C` where `B` is slow is parallelized by:

```
A | parallel --pipe B | C
```

So start by identifying the bottleneck.

For this `top` is really useful. If you see a single process running 100% in `top` that is a good candidate for parallelizing.

If not, then you may be limited by how fast your disk is, and that can rarely be sped up by GNU Parallel.

You have not included test data, so I cannot run your script and identify the bottleneck for you. But I have experience with `samtools` and `samtools view` was always the bottleneck in my scripts. So let us assume that is also the case here.

```
samtools ... | awk ...
```

This is does not fit the `A | B | C` template where `B` is slow, so we cannot use `parallel --pipe` to speed that up. If, however, `awk` is the bottleneck, then we *can* use `parallel --pipe`.

So let us instead look at the two `for` loops.

It is easy to parallelize the outer loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
files_chrM_ID="concat_chrM_*"

do_chrM() {
    ID_file="$1"
    bam_directory="../bam/"
    echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $ID_file is being treated"
    sample=${ID_file: -12}
    sample=${sample:0:8}
    echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $sample is being treated"
    for bam_file_target in "${bam_directory}"*"${sample}"*".bam"
    do
        echo $bam_file_target // $sample
        out_file=${ID_file:0:-4}_ON_${bam_file_target:8:-4}.sam
        echo "$out_file will be created"
        echo "samtools and awk starting"
        
        samtools view -@ 6 $bam_file_target | awk -v st="$ID_file" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t";ORS="\r\n"; while (getline < st) {st_array[$1]=$2}} {if ($1 in st_array) {print $0, st_array[$1], "target"}}' >> $out_file
        echo "$out_file done."
    done
}
export -f do_chrM

parallel do_chrM ::: ${files_chrM_ID}
```

This is great if there are more `${files_chrM_ID}` than there are CPU threads. But if that is not the case, we also need to parallelize the inner loop.

This is slightly trickier because we need to export a few variables to make them visible to `do_bam` which is called by `parallel`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
files_chrM_ID="concat_chrM_*"

do_chrM() {
    ID_file="$1"
    bam_directory="../bam/"
    echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $ID_file is being treated"
    sample=${ID_file: -12}
    sample=${sample:0:8}
    # We need to export $sample and $ID_file to make them visible to do_bam()
    export sample
    export ID_file
    echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $sample is being treated"
    do_bam() {
        bam_file_target="$1"
        echo $bam_file_target // $sample
        out_file=${ID_file:0:-4}_ON_${bam_file_target:8:-4}.sam
        echo "$out_file will be created"
        echo "samtools and awk starting"
        
        samtools view -@ 6 $bam_file_target | 
          awk -v st="$ID_file" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t";ORS="\r\n"; while (getline < st) {st_array[$1]=$2}} {if ($1 in st_array) {print $0, st_array[$1], "target"}}' >> $out_file
        echo "$out_file done."
    }
    export -f do_bam
    parallel do_bam ::: "${bam_directory}"*"${sample}"*".bam"
}
export -f do_chrM

parallel do_chrM ::: ${files_chrM_ID}
```

This, however, may overload your server: The inner parallel does not communicate with the outer parallel so if you run this on a 64 core machine you risk running 64*64 jobs in parallel (but only if there are enough files matching `concat_chrM_*` and `"${bam_directory}"*"${sample}"*".bam"`).

In that case it will make sense to limit the outer `parallel` to 1 or 2 jobs in parallel:

```
parallel -j2 do_chrM ::: ${files_chrM_ID}
```

This will at most run 2*64 jobs in parallel on a 64-core machine.

If, however, you want to run 64 jobs in parallel all the time then it becomes quite a bit trickier: It would have been fairly simple if the values of the inner loop did not depend on the outer loop, because then you could simply have done something like:

```
parallel do_stuff ::: chrM_1 ... chrM_100 ::: bam1.bam ... bam100.bam
```

which would generate all combinations of chrM_X,bamY.bam and run those in parallel - 64 at a time on a 64-core machine.

But in your case the values in the inner loop *do* depend on the values in the outer loop. This means you need to compute the values before starting any jobs. This also means you cannot have your script output information in the outer loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

sam_awk() {
        bam_file_target="$1"
        sample="$2"
        ID_File="$3"

        echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $ID_file is being treated"
        echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $sample is being treated"

        echo $bam_file_target // $sample
        out_file=${ID_file:0:-4}_ON_${bam_file_target:8:-4}.sam
        echo "$out_file will be created"
        echo "samtools and awk starting"

        samtools view -@ 6 $bam_file_target |
          awk -v st="$ID_file" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t";ORS="\r\n"; while (getline < st) {st_array[$1]=$2}} {if ($1 in st_array) {print $0, st_array[$1], "target"}}' >> $out_file       
        echo "$out_file done."
}

files_chrM_ID="concat_chrM_*"
bam_directory="../bam/"
for ID_file in ${files_chrM_ID}
do
# Moved to inner
#    echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $ID_file is being treated"
    sample=${ID_file: -12}
    sample=${sample:0:8}
# Moved to inner
#    echo "$(date +%H:%I:%S) $sample is being treated"
    for bam_file_target in "${bam_directory}"*"${sample}"*".bam"
    do
        echo "$bam_file_target"
        echo "$sample"
        echo "$ID_File"
    done
done | parallel -n3 sam_awk
```

Given that you have not given us any test data, I cannot test whether these scripts will actually run, so there may be errors in them.

If you have not already done so, read at least chapter 1+2 of "GNU Parallel 2018" (available at
http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html or
download it at: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014)

It should take you less than 20 minutes and your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Thanks Ole. It was complete clear and inspiring. Thank you so much